# How to recursively go through list of lists and combine the lists in different ways

Tags: list, dictionary, recursion, scheme, traversal

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650598/problems-with-recursion-trying-to-learn-scheme).

I have lists or "records" that are appended together into an empty list, that are each in the format `(Matthew (AL 21 32))`. I am now trying to write a function that would use `fetchRecord` in order to find the desired record and then multiply the two numbers inside the record. However, my current code works only if I am getting the name on the first record but it returns an empty list for any record after that. Here is my code:

```
(define (Mult_Num name)
  (cond
    [(empty? db) #f]
    [else (* (car(cdr(car(cdr (fetchRecord name)))))
             (car(cdr(cdr(car(cdr (fetchRecord name)))))))]))
```

How would I fix this? Also if a certain record has two sets of data like so: `(John (AL 25 40) (CA 40 67))` then how would you get both 25*40 and 40*67 etc., and even if it has more than two sets of data? I understand that it would be recursion but am not quite sure how you would set it up.

This is my fetchRecord function:

```
(define (fetchRecord name)
  (cond
    [(empty? db) #f]
    [(equal? (car (car db)) name) (car db)]
    [else( car (car db)) name (cdr db)]))
```

This Also may be relevant:

```
(define db '())
```

Also I have this but if I have more than two names in here it screws itself up:

```
 (define(showRec name) ;displays everything following a name. 
  (cond
    [(empty? db) #f]
    [(equal? (car (car db)) name) (cdr (fetchRecord name))]
    [else (cdr (car(fetchRecord name)))])
  )
```

Comment: There is no recursion if the function (in this case, `Bill_Amt`) does not call itself.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am trying to figure out what is wrong before I can start the recursion because It would just keep giving errors.

Comment: Please read the help on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since your question, like it is now, is not clear.

Comment: Hi, according to SO guidelines, you're supposed to post your code, your sequence of function calls (i.e. the program), its output / error message, and describe your *desired* output.  In other word, the questions here are supposed to be specific and concrete. Kind of like, "if I call *this*, I get *this*, but I expected *that* ". Best is to copy-and-past your REPL (that is, interactive prompt) transcript snippets *exactly* as is. Or use Ideone.com .

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you rely on `fetchRecord` which not only does not work, but isn't valid Scheme: the `else` clause should have only 1 argument, not 3.

And you shouldn't be surprised that a function that would use recursion to handle the `rest` of a list doesn't handle the `rest` of a list when it doesn't use recursion.